# Why the megaastrophysical objects do not collapse due to their gravitational selfattraction?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, astrophysics, space-expansion, dark-energy

At the largest scale in the universe exist formations called filaments which form something like a spider web along the whole universe. But they seem to be quite static. So my question is about the fact that as planets and stars need to orbit around each other to not to collide and cause a collapse why then these megastructures do not need the same?

Comment: They only seem static in comparison to the truly massive distances between them.

Comment: Just to expand on what @Triatticus said, how long would it take a 1 million light year object to collapse due to gravitation? You can make some back-of-a-napkin estimate by assuming a spherical object and calculating the time to fall according to Newtonian gravity.

Comment: I don't believe that there's any accessible evidence that any of the galactic filaments, whose  galaxies emitted photons that are reaching us today, still exist in the shape that those filaments had when those photons left them:  In fact, as the reduction in radiation pressure which would've resulted from the departure of those photons would've left the stars in the galaxies comprising the filaments less resistant to gravitational collapse, it seems very likely that the appearance of many of those stars would've either changed, or disappeared into black holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We live in a specific time and gather cosmological observations which we model with the mathematical  theories proven successful up to now. These theories predict and explain stable gravitational states, as planetary systems, due to the conservation laws and mathematics of gravitational attraction, so these filaments may be part of this , within the timeline that we observe.

As for the future of the universe, [there are various theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe#Theories_about_the_end_of_the_universe) you might be interested to read, and the fate of the filaments will be in accord with  the theory .

Answer (score -2):

Because dark energy stabilizes matter from such fast collapsing as it should be. Comparing to gravity, influence of dark energy is as stronger as further we look in telescopes, but gravity becomes weaker with distance. On the other side, even without dark energy in the beginning of existance our universe was very homogeneous and should stay the same, but dark matter pulled usual matter to galaxies and created "spider webs"

Comment: Dark matter and dark energy are two very different things, and you seem to be interchanging the two.

Comment: i know that they are different things, but I explained how both of them influence on universe. Edited where I accidentally confused them

Comment: It is not true that dark energy keeps galaxies from collapsing.  The angular momentum of the stars' orbits keep them from collapsing, just like the planets in the solar system. Dark energy only has meaningful effects on scales roughly on the order of the radius of the observable universe, or greater.

Comment: i deleted that sentence as I already said. Just was too sleepy